# How to Log Application Exceptions Smartly

Tags: logging

Logging is important (for diagnosis, troubleshooting and post-mortem analysis) but excessive logging degrades performance (as it is I/O intensive). In context to logging application exceptions – I am looking for some inputs and suggestions on how to log smartly. How do you decide which exception to log?  Are certain exception types logged more than other?